# What Steps Are Required to Add an additional CRM Web Server To An Existing Farm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an on premise CRM 2011 installation.  I need to add another CRM web Server (Front End Server).  I know I will need to install the CRM webserver software on the new server, I'm just not sure of what configuration will be needed for CRM to take advantage of the new server.

[This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699803.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) talks about setting everything up from scratch.  I have a live environment that I'm trying not to schedule a downtime for.  Is it possible to add a new server without disrupting service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be relatively easy to do. When you run the installer on the new server, you will choose to connect to an existing database instead of creating a new installation. When the installer is finished, you will see the new server listed in Deployment Manager.

Some other things to keep in mind:

- Is this for load-balancing? If so you'll need to check the "This deployment uses NLB" advanced setting in Deployment Manager.
- Are you installing the Async services on the second server as well? This is supported and works well, but be aware that your workflows and async plugins may run on one OR the other. This becomes important when you are debugging workflow jobs - make sure and check trace/event logs on BOTH servers for errors!
- Downtime won't necessarily be required but I still suggest doing it after hours just in case. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is already a Web01 and a Web02 server, so I'll make sure I'll check the NLB option.  There will not be Async Services on this server.  Should I be able to test it before I put it in the Load Balancer, or will the Advanced Settings in the Deployment Manager tell CRM to use it at that time?

Comment: You should be able to test it as soon as it finishes installing by using the internal URL e.g. http://servername/orgname.